# Index Match across various sheets

Tags: excel, indexing

I have a spreadsheet that contains a sheet for each month of the year, and a summary sheet.  There is a drop down that allows you to choose the month you want to review.  Based on that drop down, I want my index/match formula to reference that spreadsheet to find the values.  I'm having trouble doing that.

My formula is: '=INDEX(March!$A:$I,MATCH(Sheet1!$E6,March!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Sheet1!$G$4,March!$1:$1,0))

I want the month (which is now showing March), to reference the drop down that will change months.

For example, if the drop down is set to April, the formual would read: '=INDEX(April!$A:$I,MATCH(Sheet1!$E6,April!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Sheet1!$G$4,April!$1:$1,0))  and then reference the sheet that is labeled April.

Comment: Use INDIRECT...

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  What/how?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261